# Ajax cross domain response cookie ignored by chrome?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies

I send a cross domain ajax request, like post login, and server side return response with cookie, include sessionid, but when i check cookie in chrome, there is no cookie.

And about cross domain ajax request, the situation i think is：

Cause chrome ignore the cookie in ajax response, so, when i send another ajax request, of cause cross domain, there never ever is no cookie in request, no matter what you do, like
in client side,
set crossmain=true,
set xhrFields : {
          withCredentials : true
        },
in server side,
set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials=true

that is the brower same origin policy like?